# How can I show the values based on List Size

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Getting List of values in below code

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.AccountList}" var="ac">
```

Consider  AccountList size is 6

```
  upto AccountList size=4 (fixed)
      //I will display some images
 Remaining 2 
   // I need to display it in Table
```

How can I divide List size is Lightning Component side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't try this. But here is psuedo code to get you started.

Check the list size in lightning and based on that display images and table.

Then use `start` and `end` to give the start and end index of the list.

So your code will be

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.AccountList}" var="ac" start="0" end="4">
    show images
</aura:iteration>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.AccountList}" var="ac" start="4" >
    show table
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Looks better than I was going to suggest.